# What does it mean to make a copy of an image array?

Tags: python

I need to find a local average of each pixel--that is, the average of a specific pixel and the 8 pixels surrounding it to blur an image. It was hinted that I needed to make a copy of the image array.

What does it mean to make a copy of the image array? Also, how do I indicate that I want the surrounding pixels? If I wanted to find the average red value of a pixel, would I use the following expression:

```
im[row][col][0] = sum(im[row][col][0],im[row-1][col][0],im[row+1][col][0],im[row][col-1][0],im[row][col+1][0],im[row-1][col+1][0],im[row+1][col+1][0],im[row-1][col-1][0],im[row+1][col-1][0])/9
```

Answer (score 1):

Making a copy just means doing something like:

```
from copy import deepcopy

im_avg = deepcopy(im)
```

This means you can do your calculations and save the result to a different data structure, so that the original values stick around to be used in the calculation for other pixels. You need to use deepcopy instead of just copy or `im[:]` because it looks like your image is a set of nested lists, in which case a shallow copy wouldn't fully isolate the new set of values.

Using this, you would then use `im_avg` to *store* the averaged values, but the original `im` to calculate them from.

The expression you have for the average calculation looks reasonable, although you could look into the standard itertools module to help simplify it if you chose to.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the from import statement? Is "copy" or "deepcopy" the copied array in which values will be reassigned? Also, the expression for averaging returned an error: "sum expected at most 2 arguments, got 9".

Comment: @pubkitty `from copy import deepcopy` imports the function called `deepcopy` from the stdlib module `copy`. The *result* of calling this function (ie, `im_avg`) is the copied data structure - so you could do `im_avg[row][col][0] = sum(...)`. That error with sum is because it expects all the things being summed to be bundled into a single iterable, so wrap them in another set of `()` to put them in a tuple and it will be happy.

Answer (score 1):

It was probably recommended to make a copy of the image array to ensure that you do not modify the original image array as you calculate local averages.

Technically you should not need to make a copy of the array, as you could create a new blank array with the same size as the image array and populate it with values.

Your logic for calculating the average red value from the 3x3 grid surrounding it is correct.